# help fixing winehq error : hera Release does not have a Release file

Tags: wine

I'm using Elementary Juno, as a first entry in the world of linux. So far I dont know much, especially when it comes to use the terminal.

I managed to install Wine, but I still have an error left : "'dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file"

I tried one workaround posted here in reply of the same problem, but it didnt work :

"To solve the error open terminal and run:
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:versable/elementary-update
For hash sum mismatch run:
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
Now run:
sudo apt-get update"

In the end I still get the same error about 'dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hera Release' not having a Release file, and something about the updates that cant be done because its not secured.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

//

Edit : @Vlad Pop, here's the content of my sources.list file.

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./
# deb-src https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an incorrect repository defined in your sorces list. There is no 'hera' distribution at https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/; but there is a bionic one (elementary OS hera is based on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic)

What you'll have to do is to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and replace `hera` with `bionic` in the line that reads:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hera main
```

so that it becomes

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

You'll need sudo privileges for this: right-click the Files app -> New Window as Administrator -> navigate to /etc/apt -> open sources.list in Code -> carefully edit and save -> run `sudo apt update` to verify the changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Vlad, and sorry for the late feedback. I followed your instructions and it looks like it worked fine. The only thing that might be a problem now is that I get a lot of lines in the terminal mentioning that some targets (eg : DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar)) are specified several times in  /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:18. I guess its because when I replaced "hera" with "bionic" i didnt notice there was a bionic line already there. should i remove those duplicates line or it doesnt matter ?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your sources.list file. Can you add its contents to the original post please? Or at least post the lines 16 and 18 from your sources.list. Anyway, as a general rule, avoid having duplicate entries here. Comment the lines, and delete them only after verifying.

Comment: I updated the content of my first post with the content of 'sources.list' file. Indeed Lines 16 & 18 seems to be duplicates so I'll comment line 18 and see what happens next. 
Edit : done ! All seems in order now. 
Thanx for your help !!

Comment: Hey, always happy when things work out! Now please accept the answer so that it can help others aswell.

Comment: done ! (sorry i'm not familiar with this ^^)