# eOS cannot update

Tags: release-hera, updates, repositories, sources

Okay, there's few things I need to clear first:

I was using eOS for about a month when I ran into some issues and decided to restore Timeshift image. To my surprise it did not work as expected and done more harm. After like a week of back and forth between new installs and restores from various Timeshift images I finally settled for a workable system.

The thing is, however, now, after few more reinstall there are few issues with my eOS:

- I cannot update (terminal result follows)
- I cannot install repositories
- My Settings-About says I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I should have Hera 5.1.4 or .6

I did try following commands but none have helped:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Anyone knows what's wrong and how to fix it (without another reinstall)?

sudo apt-get update

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera InRelease               
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                
Ign:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease    
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-updates InRelease                              
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu hera InRelease   
Err:8 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-backports InRelease                            
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                   
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]                 
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security Release                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]               
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera Release                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu hera Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-updates Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:20 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter hera InRelease
Err:21 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter hera Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.4.44 80]
Hit:22 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                                         
Reading package lists... Done                                                              
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter hera Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Following is the /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 5.1 _hera_ - stable amd64 (20200706)]/ bionic contrib main non-free
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 5.1 _hera_ - stable amd64 (20200706)]/ bionic contrib main non-free
# deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt hera main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt hera main restricted universe multiverse
# deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt hera-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt hera-updates main restricted universe multiverse

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hera-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: First thing to try is to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `hera` with `bionic` in the entire file (for example `hera-updates` should be `bionic-updates`, `hera-security` becomes `bionic-security` etc) and comment the `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04` line (that ppa  is no longer available. Add the output of `sudo apt-get update` to your question after making those changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [help fixing winehq error : hera Release does not have a Release file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/help-fixing-winehq-error-hera-release-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Already tried that before. Now the output is:
```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                                          
Ign:3 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease    
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:11 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:11 and /etc/apt/sources.list:61
... ```

Comment: There is no "http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04" in the sources.list

Comment: Take a look in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` you might find that elusive opensuse reppo there (each .list file here is a repo). I would also look for the playonlinux one, since it points to trusty, and this does not seem right. And please look carefully in your sources.list file, lines 11 and 61 are identical, comment one of them.   As a side note, when adding repos, make sure they have software for your distro, in our case make sure they reference bionic (not trusty) or ubuntu 18.04 (not 16.04). Using outdated repos is strongly frouned uppon :D

Comment: Nothing with "opensuse" in the name in /etc/apt/sources.list.d.    
Yeah, playonlinux.list has "trusty" in it. Should I delete it or change it to "bionic"?    
When installing some software, I usually follow a guide. That might be how old repos ended up there.

Comment: Oh, wait! I found the opensuse in lutris.list. Changing it to 18.04 sends me to opensuse error website and changing it to `https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_18.04/` doesn't help either. :(

Comment: playonlinux is available in the default repos, no need for a different source, particularly an old one. I think you can safely delete it. When following tutorials, make sure they apply to Ubuntu 18.04 bionic. Old tutorials might work, but then you end up with old repos in yout apt list. FOr lutris, you should only need `ppa:lutris-team/lutris`.  If you also need to install Wine, give this a look https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25260/i-cannot-install-wine